# cascading foreign key 'X' cannot be created where the referencing column 'Y' is an identity column

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to upgrade the [OwnedTypes sample](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/core/Modeling/OwnedEntities) to EF Core 3.0 Preview 8 but when I run the project it can't create the database.

When `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()` is called the following exception is thrown:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Cascading foreign key 'FK_OrderDetails_DetailedOrders_OrderId' cannot be created where the referencing column 'OrderDetails.OrderId' is an identity column.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.'

What previous errors?

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{            
    #region OwnsOneNested
    modelBuilder.Entity<DetailedOrder>().OwnsOne(p => p.OrderDetails, od =>
    {
        od.OwnsOne(c => c.BillingAddress);
        od.OwnsOne(c => c.ShippingAddress);
    });
    #endregion

    #region OwnsOneTable
    modelBuilder.Entity<DetailedOrder>().OwnsOne(p => p.OrderDetails, od =>
    {
        od.OwnsOne(c => c.BillingAddress);
        od.OwnsOne(c => c.ShippingAddress, sa =>
        {
            sa.Ignore(p => p.IgnoreMe);
        });
        od.ToTable("OrderDetails");
    });
    #endregion
}
```

[Full project](https://github.com/spottedmahn/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/null-owned-type-3.0/samples/core/Modeling/OwnedEntities)

I assume there is something in the [3.0 breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) list I need to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can remove `od.ToTable("OrderDetails");` to map `OrderDetails` to the same table as `DetailedOrder`
- You can add `od.Property("OrderId").ValueGeneratedNever();` to disable marking the `OrderId` column as identity